# What is the translation of "afternoon" in Russian language?

Tags: выбор-слова

What is the common translation for '**afternoon**' in Russian language?

I've checked the dictionary and I found *many options* which some of them seems to be incorrect at all. Look at the attached picture. 
[image]

Comment: Это смысловое слово. Скорее всего Вам подойдет - "день" или "обед".

Comment: So, which expression would a teacher use to tell the class "This afternoon we're going to watch a movie in Englisch class."?

Comment: @Thomas, there need not be a definite exact translation. Russian day is divided differently to the English one, and people _think_ differently about it. If it's before about 4-5 pm (but not in the morning, i.e. after 10-11 am), it would be "днём" [мы пойдём...]; if later (but before dark) - "вечером". The noon (полдень) is just less significant as a reference. It is possible to translate exactly (as the accepted answer suggests), but people don's say that as commonly (as "afternoon" is used in English).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Вторая половина дня** is OK. **In** the afternoon - "**во второй половине дня**" (this part of day usually excludes evening) or - in less formal context - "**днём**" (this just excludes morning and evening). *Пополудни* is mainly used to specify time (functions as 'PM/p.m.'), e. g. **в два часа пополудни** (at 2:00 PM).

Comment: And "после обеда" ("after lunch") is a colloquial counterpart of "во второй половине дня".

Comment: _После обеда_ is typical for workplace context (common lunch time), it can mean either the second part of a working day or just the time immediately after lunch.

Comment: I agree that outside of contexts where lunch is firmly scheduled the expression is somewhat inaccurate, but I use it anyway.